# What is a substitute for maple extract?

Tags: substitutions, extracts

I am making cinnamon rolls with a maple flavoured frosting, however, I am having trouble finding maple extract for the frosting. What can I substitute it with? I have vanilla extract - will it change the taste of the topping too much if I use this?

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to substitute the extract with maple syrup?

Comment: No, not really; maple extract is highly concentrated.  You would need to add a very large amount of maple syrup to compensate and that would probably turn your frosting into a soup.

Comment: I would say bourbon. But then, I always say that.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you are not going to get a *maple* flavour with anything other than *maple* extract (or maple sugar or syrup or some similar maple product).

That said, I've substituted *rum* for maple in some recipes and tend to think of it as a better approximation than vanilla.  The caveat of course is the amount; a tablespoon is fine to substitute, an entire cup is going to impart a pretty strong alcohol flavour that you probably don't want.

If you don't have rum or don't think it would work for your recipe, then vanilla extract is probably the next-closest thing.  However, it *will* change the flavour; whether or not that change is "too much" is really a matter of opinion.

Comment: As a slight tweak, I might go for Amaretto instead of rum - the nuttiness reminds me a bit more of maple than rum does.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking to retain the maple flavor, or simply for a flavor that will be complimentary to your cinnamon rolls?  In many ways, you could use all sorts of extracts, but your cinnamon rolls will be a different flavor.  Orange extract might be nice.  Almond extract always provides a very delicate flavor (unless you use too much, then it's overpowering) and would also work well.  Rum extract would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla extract. That's what I used and it might have a strange taste but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that' butter vanilla will do the - closest - to the same thing ? not 100% yet. about to make a recipe with this instead of the maple extract I'll keep you updated.